# Obtaining the text value of uidatepicker - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, text

I have an input textfield in my html file:

```
<p>From Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I assign, using jQuery a uidatepicker to this textfield:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    maxDate: new Date(theDate.getFullYear(), theDate.getMonth(), theDate.getDate())
});
```

Once the user selects a date, they press the "Go" button. I need to obtain the date entered into the textfield via the datepicker. I have tried:

```
$("#go").click(function(e){             
     alert($("#datepicker").text());  //doesn't work         
}
```

but it doesn't work....

**EDIT:**

Ok so after messing about the following works:

```
alert($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate"));
```

But the output is:

```
Tue Aug 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

I want it just as `dd-mm-yy`. I have already set the `dateFormat` for my datepicker, so I'm not sure how to get the correct output....

Comment: Have you tried `.val()`?

Comment: doesn't val return the value attribute? why would I need that?

Comment: I don't know why you would need it, but that's what you asked for. Anything entered into the textfield would be the value.

Comment: Ahhh I get it. I will give ti a go and update! thanks

Comment: excellent = it works...can u write the answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.text()` with `.val()` to be able to read the values placed into the textfield of the datepicker.